# Python requests returns incomprehensible content

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to parse the site. I don't want to use selenium. Requests is coping. BUT! something strange is happening. I can't cut out the text I need with a regular expression (and it's there - you can see it if you do print(data.text)) But re  doesn't see him. If this text is copied to notepad++, it outputs this - it sees these characters as a single line.

```
import requests
import re

data = requests.get('https://ru.runetki3.com/?page=1')

print(data.text)
```

What is it and how to work with it?[pay attention to the line numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7jG2.png)

Comment: And what text are you looking for, if I dare to ask ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Are you asking why there's a long line with a long line of incomprehensible data in the HTML that's returned by your query?  The answer to that question is a function of what the page is doing.   As to how to work with it, what do you want to do with it?  You mention a regular expression that you've applied to the result, but you don't show it.  Providing that, and explaining what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: I need to find all "username", all "display-name" and all links to images "i.bimbolive.com ". How to do it?

Comment: for example to find names I use 
`names  = re.findall(r'"username":"(.+)"', data.text)`
but it doesn't work. Rather, it works, but not at all as it should.

Comment: Don't use `.`, use `\w` instead (or a variation of that, adjusted to your needs. For example, `print(re.findall(r'"username":"([\w|-]+)"',data.text))` return names, including those with `-` in them; you may have a look at other "non \w" character that appear in names and complete the regex.

Comment: @Swifty Thanks! Very helpful. I'm not good at regular expressions, but usually `(.+)` it worked as it should. I'm going to read guides on re...

Comment: Well `.` matches almost any character, and `+` being greedy will return the longest chain between "username":" and "; so indeed read a tutorial on regex, and try to always fit your regex very closely to the chars you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use their Ajax API to load all usernames + thumb images:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://ru.runetki3.com/tools/listing_v3.php?livetab=female&offset=0&limit={}'

headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

all_data = []
for p in range(1, 4):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    data = requests.get(url.format(p * 144), headers=headers).json()
    for m in data['models']:
        all_data.append((m['username'], m['display_name'], m['thumb_image'].replace('{ext}', 'jpg')))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=['username', 'display_name', 'thumb'])
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
     username  display_name                                                  thumb
0     wetlilu   Little_Lilu  //i.bimbolive.com/live/034/263/131/xbig_lq/c30823.jpg
1  mellannie8  mellannieSEX  //i.bimbolive.com/live/034/24f/209/xbig_lq/314348.jpg
2    mokkoann      mokkoann  //i.bimbolive.com/live/034/270/279/xbig_lq/cb25cb.jpg
3    ogurezzi  CynEp-nuCbka  //i.bimbolive.com/live/034/269/02c/xbig_lq/3ebe2a.jpg
4   Pepetka22     _-Katya-_  //i.bimbolive.com/live/034/24f/36e/xbig_lq/18da8e.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `.` in a regex unless you really want to get any character; here, the usernames (as far as I can see) only contain `-` and alphanumeric characters, so you can retrieve them with:

```
re.findall(r'"username":"([\w|-]+)"',data.text)
```

An even simpler way, which will remove the need to deal with special characters by getting all characters except `"` is:

```
re.findall(r'"username":"([^"]+)"',data.text)
```

So here's a way of getting the info you seek (I joined them into a dictionary, but you can change that to whatever you prefer):

```
import requests
import re

data = requests.get('https://ru.runetki3.com/?page=1')
with open ("return.txt",'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    f.write(data.text)

names = re.findall(r'"username":"([^"]+)"',data.text)
disp_names = re.findall(r'"display_name":"([^"]+)"',data.text)
thumbs = re.findall(r'"thumb_image":"([^"]+)"',data.text)

names_dict = {name:[disp, thumb.replace('{ext}', 'jpg')] for name, disp, thumb in zip(names, disp_names, thumbs)}
```

**Example**

```
names_dict['JuliaCute']
# ['_Cute',
#  '\\/\\/i.bimbolive.com\\/live\\/055\\/2b0\\/15d\\/xbig_lq\\/d89ef4.jpg']
```